# How many hours are on a transit visa through Canada?

Tags: transit-visas, air-canada, yyz

I have a week until my flight which is Frankfort to Toronto. I get to Toronto at 7:00 p.m. and my flight to get to West Palm Beach is at 9:00 a.m.

Can I get out of the airport because I have a transit visa?

How many hours are on the transit visa?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Does Canada have a transit visa that is different from a visitor visa?

Comment: @Dennis:  [Yes.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=420&top=16)

Comment: @mkennedy Does Canada have different transit visas for different nationalities?

Comment: Asking about visas a week before you travel is rather leaving it until the last minute.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I didn't know when I asked about the OP's citizenship, but yes, it matters.

Comment: @mkennedy The only relevance seems to be whether the asker needs a transit visa at all. The answer seems to imply that, if the asker does need a transit visa, there is only one kind.

Answer (score 3):

A Canadian transit visa allows entry for up to 48 hours each entry. You are allowed to leave the airport. (And there is no fee for the transit visa, but you may have to pay a VFS service charge.)

Details are [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=420&top=16). As of 27 February 2017:

> If you need a visa to visit Canada, then you need a transit visa to
>   travel through Canada without stopping or visiting. This is true even
>   if you are in Canada for less than 48 hours. There is no fee for a
>   transit visa. You can apply for a transit visa by filling out the
>   application for a visitor visa (Temporary Resident Visa) and selecting
>   transit visa from the list of options on the form.
>
> If you need an eTA
>   to visit Canada, then you also need an eTA to transit through Canada
>   without stopping or visiting. An eTA costs $7 CAD and it only takes a
>   few minutes to apply for one.
>
> You may not need a transit visa or an
>   eTA if you travel to or from the United States. The Transit Without
>   Visa program (TWOV) and the China Transit Program (CTP) allow certain
>   foreign nationals to transit through Canada on their way to and from
>   the United States without a Canadian transit visa or eTA, if they meet
>   certain requirements.
>
> New entry requirement now in effect
>
> Visa-exempt foreign nationals need an Electronic Travel Authorization
>   (eTA) to fly to or transit through Canada. Exceptions include U.S.
>   citizens and travellers with a valid Canadian visa. Canadian citizens,
>   including dual citizens, and Canadian permanent residents cannot apply
>   for an eTA.

Comment: there is no need to pay VFS. Use the "free" option - apply online.